# QGraphicsView not displaying in QMainWindow

Tags: python, user-interface, qt, frameworks, pyqt

I'm not sure why this application is not displaying anything. I'll reproduce in a few lines to provide the gist of the issue. Using PyQt4

```
class SomeScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QGraphicsScene.__init__(self, parent)

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('someImage') # path is DEFINITELY valid
        item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap)
        self.addItem(item)


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        ... # code to set up window

        scene = SomeScene()
        view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(scene)

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(view)

        mainWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        mainWidget.setLayout(hbox)

        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = MainWindow()
mainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This would just show a blank space.

Comment: Fixed problem, but very strange. You can't initialize 'view' with the scene, even though the documentation indicates you can. Instead you need to use the default constructor, then manually call view.setScene(scene) afterwards.

Comment: That is strange. The equivalent code to yours in C++ works fine. In my code though, I set the parent to "self" for SomeScene(), QHBoxLayout() and QWidget().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view is blank because the scene has been destroyed. The scene is destroyed if it is not stored in a member variable. The view does not take ownership of the scene since a scene can have multiple views. With the example below, the tmpScene will be destroyed (causing a "tmpScene destroyed" message to be printed), but the self.scene will be used in the view and the pixmap item will be displayed.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sip

class SomeScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QGraphicsScene.__init__(self, parent)

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('someImage')
        item = QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap)
        self.addItem(item)


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        # This scene will be destroyed because it is local.
        tmpScene = SomeScene()
        tmpScene.destroyed.connect(self.onSceneDestroyed)

        self.scene = SomeScene()
        view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self.scene)

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(view)

        mainWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        mainWidget.setLayout(hbox)

        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)

    def onSceneDestroyed(self, obj):
        print 'tmpScene destroyed'

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = MainWindow()
mainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought the view was taking ownership.